# Img embedding problem in Struts2 jsp page

Tags: html, jsp, iframe, struts2

I have a page called home.jsp in my struts2 application. I have embedded a html (screencompany.html) page within this home.jsp. I am trying to embed an image within the html page. But the image is not loading. Please help me out. Im very new to struts2 and jsp.

Here is the home.jsp code.

```
<iframe id="displayFrame" src="http://localhost:3000/jebran/pages/documents/screencompany.html" width="100%" height="500" ></iframe>
```

Here is the code from screencompany.html

```
 <h1>Illustration 1</h1><br/>
<img src="./images/illus1.gif" width="601" height="128" border="0"/>
```

The text is loading correctly but the image is not. It only shows a blank area of the specified size, unable to load the  image.

Answer (score 1):

if the `images/illus1.gif` file is in the same directory as the `screencompany.html` file, then you can omit the dot,as well as the leading slash.

Comment: Thanks a lot it was a silly mistake of giving wrong path. Sorry.